# How to create a query for MongoDB dynamically using JObject in .NET Core WebAPI for a GetByQuery(JObject query) end point inC#

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, mongodb-.net-driver

I have to create a query for a fetch operation from MongoDB which is accessible through CosmosDB API.
Below is my query:

```
Destinations destinations = GetDestinations();
dynamic query = new JObject();
query.destinationName = destinations.DestinationName;
query.endPointURL = destinations.EndPointURL;

var matchedObjList = await _repository.FetchByQuery(query);
```

In the above query, It is generating the query as {"destinationName":"value1"},{"endPointURL":"value2"} which is a AND operation between the two conditions, but i want the query should be generated using OR operator.

Can you please help me how do i get the proper query which will be a "OR"ed between two conditions?
I do not want to generate the query by hard coding.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `FetchByQuery` method you have today?

Comment: @BrianRogers, i'm able to get a solution using the Newtonsoft.Json.Linq classes like JArray, JObject and JProperty.

Comment: That's great.  You can add an answer to your own question if you like so it will help other people in the future.